# h2o : Any components not running or stored on local machine?

Tags: h2o

The descriptive language used when referencing how h2o works is a little confusing to me at times (e.g., client, cluster, "internet"). I try to remain vigilant in not uploading or exposing my datasets - with everything always conducted on the local machine (e.g., PC).

So if using the below R code, are any data or specifics related to the analysis ever being ran, saved, accessible not on the local machine? Given data is accessed from a local source and R or python ran on the local machine and cluster based on cores. So is anything happening not on the local machine or accessible via internet connection that may compromised the confidentiality/security of the dataset being used?

```
install.packages("h2o")
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
train <- h2o.importFile("C:/Datafile.csv")
automl_model <- h2o.automl(y = "Outcome", 
                  training_frame = train,
                  max_models = 8,
                  seed = 12345,
                  nfolds = 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

H2O-3 holds data in-memory on the hosts where the H2O nodes are started.  In this case, that would be the one node on your windows computer.

H2O-3 does not need to talk to anything on the internet, and runs fine in environments that are not connected to the internet.  (Many corporate data centers run disconnected from the internet.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything is on the "h2o cluster". For example, if you are running h2o on a Hadoop cluster, in which case the "h2o cluster" is also run on the Hadoop cluster, then everything is on the Hadoop cluster (i.e. in hdfs). To get anything off the h2o cluster, you probably need to "download" it, to your local file system (or programming environment).

Not quite sure about the security implementation though, maybe h2o's official site is a good start? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/security.html

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  I would use local machine and not implement Flow.  I run "h2.init" and get: R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
     H2O cluster uptime:         15 seconds 900 milliseconds 
 .. .H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
 H2O cluster total memory:   0.96 GB 
 H2O cluster total cores:    4 
 H2O cluster allowed cores:  4 
 H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
   ...
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE

Comment: I construe this as it is running on a cluster on my machine. Not sure it that is correct or not. I also kind of think it is connecting the R session with the cluster via a webportal, But if that is happening, is it local or via the world wide web?

Comment: You are correct, in your case, the h2o cluster is on your local machine as well, just as a Java Virtual Machine (if I understand) correctly. Once the h2o cluster is up (after the h2o.init() command), you could still use flow through your web browser, usually at http://localhost:54321. I do find the web interface convenient at times. 

There is no outgoing Internet connection.